# Setting fraction equal to each other with the same numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have 2 fractions and set them equal to each other, can we remove the numerator without changing the equation? So the demonators would just equal eachother, so $4p = 8$ Like this:

$$\frac{1}{4p} = \frac{1}{8}$$
Multiply each side by 4p:

$$\frac{4p*1}{4p} = \frac{4p*1}{8}$$
Then we cross out each 4p on the LHS:
$$1 = \frac{4p}{8}$$
Then times each side by 8 to isolate p:
$$1*8 = \frac{4p*8}{8}$$
And finnally we cross out each 8 on the LHS and left with:
$$8= 4p$$
Can we do this with any number? Assuming of course the number is real.

Comment: Yes, if $1/x=1/y$  then $x=y$ ($x$ and $y$ nonzero reals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{c}$$

where $a \ne 0$.

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{bc}{a}$ gives us $c=b$.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thought!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p \neq 0 $ (which is necessary for  LHS not being undefined), you can directly multiply by the denominators' Minimum Common Multiple to yield:

$$
\frac{1}{4p}=\frac{1}{8} \quad\bigg|\cdot 32p \iff 8=4p \iff p=2$$

**Another point of view:**

> The function $\,\,f(x):=\frac1x, \quad f: \mathbb{R^*}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R^*}\,\,$ is **bijective** (or one-to-one), which by definition means that:
>
> $$\textit{If}\quad f(a)=f(b)\quad \textbf{then}\quad a=b$$

Your equation is nothing else than

$$f(4p)=f(8)$$

Considering $f$'s  bijective:

$$4p=8 \iff p=2$$